# How to check if a file with date name exists from inside a batch file and create file

Tags: batch-file

i got task to make batch file that can detect a file that specified with date in it name. if there is a file exist with that name, the batch process to make empty file with that name.

example :
to check if file named `INT_SK_20170405.txt` exists, if it doesnt exist then make new empty file named `INT_SK_20170405.txt`

please help

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you are asking. Also you didn't provide any code or anything you tried so far. If you just want to check if a file exists and create it if it doesn't, you can do `if not exist "C:\PATH\TO\FILE\INT_SK_20170405.txt" copy /y nul INT_SK_20170405.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the date independent of time settings with WMIC.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYYMMDD=%dt:~0,8%" 

if not exist "INT_SK_%YYYYMMDD%.txt" break>"INT_SK_%YYYYMMDD%.txt"
```

with tomorrow's date:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq" %%# in (`"powershell (Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')"`) do set "YYYYMMDD=%%#"

if not exist "INT_SK_%YYYYMMDD%.txt" break>"INT_SK_%YYYYMMDD%.txt"
```

Comment: thanks it works, but what if the file that i want to check in the other directory, and the date is tommorow date, can we add a mathematical function with it? sry for my bad english